# Bower .bowerrc (directory) is not overiding default

Tags: bower, bower-install

I am having trouble installing files with the appropriate name folder and sub folder.  Bower 1.4.1

In project root directory. I've added .bowerrc

```
{ "directory": "public/lib" }
```

When I run "bower install angular", the files are being added to the default folder bower_components. I've already tried removing bower and installing it. I've already looked into the bower configuration page. I can't seem to get it to work the way I want it to. Any solutions to my problem?